# Python + Selenium: wait for disappearance of web element

Tags: python, selenium

I use WebDriver wait, but I have a question. 
On the page appears an element that disappears after 3 seconds. I want to stop the test for this time and resume it after this time (without sleep). How I can do this? I ty with WebDriver:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15, poll_frequency=0.5, ignored_exceptions[ElementNotVisibleException, ElementNotSelectableException,NoSuchElementException, WebDriverException]).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(FormPage.name))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `invisibility_of_element_located` expected condition for that:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


ui.WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "your_css_selector")))
```

PS: You can use any other locators (ID, name, and so on).

Hope it helps you!